# custom Edit/New/display Form at modern experience

Tags: modern-experience, read-only

As we know at Modern page at SharePoint Online, the New/Edit/display Form are all combined in one output,

In my case, I need to set one field as hidden in edit / new form ; but visible at display form .

using : `ShowInNewForm= "False"` works verry good at the old experience but at the modern experience ;

even using `ReadOnly`.

any idea ?

Comment: Is using powerapp an option for you? and using option like: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Setting-the-Disabled-Property-on-a-text-field/td-p/17870

Comment: Hello , Powerapp is not an option for me .